# How do I calculate the following conditional moments: $\mathbb{E}[X|(S_1,\dots,S_k)], \quad \mathbb{V}ar[X|(S_1,\dots,S_k)] ...$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Suppose that $X$ denotes a discrete random variable. Let $f(\cdot)$ be the PDF (which is in fact the probability mass function since $X$ is discrete) of $X$ with finite support $[\underline{X}, \overline{X}]$ such that $X\sim f_X(X)$. A multivariate signal of dimension $k$ such that $S = (S_1,\dots,S_k) \sim f_S(S|X)$ with finite support as well,that is $[\underline{S}, \overline{S}]$. The signal is correlated with the random variable $\theta$. My question is how do I calculate the following conditional moments?

$$\mathbb{E}[X|(S_1,\dots,S_k)], \quad \operatorname{\mathbb{V}ar}[X|(S_1,\dots,S_k)]$$

Comment: Do you really mean that $\theta$ has PDF $f_{\theta}(x)$? And what is meant by the covariance of $\theta$?  The notation $\theta \sim f(\theta)$ is not good. I suggest you use random variable $X$ and $S=(S_1, ..., S_k)$. And the PDFs are $f_X(x)$, $f_{S|X}(s|x)$.

Comment: If $X$ is a random variable with PDF $f_X(x)$ with support $x \in [a,b]$, and $S$ is a random vector that takes values over a box $B\subseteq\mathbb{R}^k$ and has conditional PDF $f_{S|X}(s|x)$ then $$E[X|S=s]=\int_a^bxf_{X|S}(x|s)dx$$ where $$f_{X|S}(x|s)=\frac{f_{S|X}(s|x)f_X(x)}{f_S(s)}=\frac{f_{S|X}(s|x)f_X(x)}{\int_a^b f_{S|X}(s|t)f_X(t)dt}$$ Also $Var(X|S=s)=E[X^2|S=s]-E[X|S=s]^2$. It does not make sense to talk about $Cov(X)$ as it would be $Cov(X)=Var(X)$.

Comment: why is does not make sense to talk about $Cov(X)$? Isn't there a formula about this?

Comment: What is your working definition of $Cov(X)$ for a random variable $X$?

Comment: Sorry...you are right....I need two variables to calculate their covariances :P

Comment: If you want to use a PMF for a discrete case then you change the integrals to sums. It helps to distinguish between a PMF, PDF, CDF. The small-case $f$ is often used for PDF.

Comment: However, the variable $X$ is correlated with the signal $S$. This does not change anyhting in how we calculate the conditional mean and the variance...What we need to be sute is that the joint probability density (or mass) function is defined...right?

Comment: The fact that you use a conditional PDF $f_{S|X}(s|x)$ suggests that $S$ and $X$ can be dependent and hence possibly correlated, and (assuming both $S$ and $X$ are continuous) it is defined by the joint PDF $$f_{S|X}(s|x)=\frac{f_{S,X}(s,x)}{f_X(x)}$$ and $$f_{X|S}(x|s)=\frac{f_{X,S}(x,s)}{f_S(s)}=\frac{f_{S,X}(s,x)}{f_S(s)}=\frac{f_{S|X}(s|x)f_X(x)}{f_S(s)}$$

Comment: @Michael thanks!